# What is this dual handled input called?

Tags: vue.js, input, controls

Anyone know what these control inputs are called? Or even better, know of a Vue library that has them? I can't really google the answer, because I don't know what to google!
[Dual handled input, commonly seen for easing functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ilv0.jpg)

Comment: The question isn't well suited for so. Search for "spline" or "bezier" editor. It's not supposed to be Vue lib, this is pure JS functionality that needs to be wrapped with Vue comp

Comment: Spline is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is the [smooth shadow generator](https://shadows.brumm.af/) created by @brumm

Comment: Not really an answer. But I found this widget useful